# Cannot Create User Groups in TFS 2017 for Release Approval

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management

We're using TFS 2017 for our CI/CD and I'm trying to configure the users for the Approvals on the production Environment definition of a Release definition.

What I'm try to achieve is assigning two groups of users as approvers, one member of each being required to sign off the release.  The screens suggest this should be possible but it's proving difficult to configure.

I've created a Project Manager group and an Infrastructure Team group, both at a TFS collection level and at the project level within TFS and assigned the appropriate members.

Having created the *Release* definition and created a production *Environment*, I select the `Assign Approvers...` which displays a new window.  I select the 
`Pre-deployment approver` | `Specific Users` option, click the `More Options` link and select the `All users in any order` option.

However, when I try to select the groups, it doesn't show me any of the groups I've created and I can't select them.

I know that I should be able to manage this via AD but I don't want to have to keep getting AD groups made for me if I can manage this myself within TFS.

Has anyone managed to achieve this in TFS 2017 and could you tell me how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can create the Groups in both **Collection** and **Project** level and can select them to Release Approval. Everything works correctly.

Please note that the Groups will not display automatically, you need to enter the Group name in the `Search user and groups` text box to filter it out.  Just have try for that.

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy,  Thanks for the confirmation - I went back to this piece of work and found it exactly as you said.  I then found out that we had some AD issues yesterday and the day before which were impacting replication, so I'm going to chalk it up to that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Typing group name doesn't help, newly created groups don't appear in suggestion list. If I manually enter entire group name, system doesn't allow me to save this.